# GAEとAndroidの連携について

Tags: android, google-app-engine

現在Google App Engine（GAE）とAndroidを連携させたアプリの開発をしています。 
主な処理内容としてはAndroid端末から画像をGAEのBlobStoreにアップロードするというものです。

手順としましては、 
①Androidからサーバーにアクセスし、Blobkeyを取得 
②取得したBlobkeyに画像データをアップロード

そして問題としましては、 
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL); 
を行った時にIllegalArgumentExceptionが発生してしまいます。 
Java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path index 256:

おそらく引数のＵＲＬが長すぎる為と考えているのですが、こちらの対処法または別の方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら教えていただきたいです。 
ちなみにＵＲＬの部分に入る文字の長さはlengthで測ったところ２５７文字でした。

以下がソースとなります。

クライアント側（Android4.0）

```
 public void run() {
    /*▼▼▼BlobKey取得▼▼▼*/
    String url = "http://xxxxxxxx.appspot.com/android";
    String bkey = "";
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        bkey = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
    /*▲▲▲ここまで▲▲▲*/


    /*▼▼▼アップロード▼▼▼*/
    try {
        String fileName = "xxx.png";
        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        if(bkey != null) {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(bkey);
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
            builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            File file = new File(fileName);
            FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file);
            builder.addPart("myFile", fileBody);
            httpPost.setEntity(builder.build());
            httpClient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    /*▲▲▲ここまで▲▲▲*/
}}
```

サーバー側（servret JDK1.7）

```
public class BlobUploadServlet extends HttpServlet {
private BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
BlobInfoFactory factory = new BlobInfoFactory();

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {

    Map<String, List<BlobKey>> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploads(req);
    List<BlobKey> bkList = blobs.get("myFile");
    BlobKey blobKey = bkList.get(0);   // type="file"の name
    if ( blobKey == null ) {
        // 失敗
        resp.sendRedirect("/");
    } else {
        PersistenceManagerFactory pmf = PMF.get();
        PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();

        //datastore
        BlobInfo blobInfo =  factory.loadBlobInfo(blobKey);
        String filename = blobInfo.getFilename();
        String fileurl = blobKey.getKeyString();
        Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        SampleData2 data = new SampleData2(filename,fileurl,date);

        try {
            pm.makePersistent(data);
        } finally {
            pm.close();
        }
        //resp.sendRedirect("/viewer?blob-key=" + blobKey.getKeyString()); //直接画像へジャンプ
        resp.sendRedirect("/viewersd2");
    }
}}
```

Comment: URLはどう生成してるんでしょう？2バイト文字のファイル名をそのままURLにしているような挙動に見えます。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。載せ忘れていました。別のサーブレットでこのように作成しています。
BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();

String uploadUrl = blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/uploader");

resp.getWriter().println(uploadUrl);

Comment: @maka

質問の回答ではないのですが、App EngineのBlobStoreServiceを利用する場合、データの保存先はCloud StorageのDefault Bucketにするのが良いかと思います。
BlobStoreは今後も生き残るのかが怪しいので。

http://qiita.com/sinmetal/items/f2f7e0fe444b7e000a61

Comment: 教えて頂きありがとうございます。
残りが完成次第そちらもやっていきたいと思います。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

まず、
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(bkey);
としていますが、bkeyに入ってるのはキー文字列だけで、URLになっていないと予想しますがいかがでしょう。
もし、変数bkeyがブロブキーをパラメータに持つURLならURLとブロブキーを分ける必要があります。

分けた上で、
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(bkey);
httpPost.getParameters().put("blob-key", bkey);
といった感じでパラメータとして渡してあげればURLが長くなることは無くなるはずです。
※末尾のコードはうろ覚えなのでコンパイルエラーが出ないように調整してみてください

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。
uploadUrl = blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/uploader");
で作ったURLにそのまま画像をアップロードすればいいと勘違いしていました。
勉強不足の為、変数bkeyがブロブキーをパラメータに持つURLかどうかの確認方法がわからないのですが、どこで判断すればいいのでしょうか？

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17771706

Comment: すみません、操作ミスで先に書いてしまいましたが上記のトピックだとアップロード用URLの末尾のスラッシュを除いたら解決したようです。

runメソッドの変数名からblobkeyとURLを分けて扱うことを意図していると推定していましたが、createUploadUrlで生成しているのなら分ける必要はありませんでした。失礼しました。

Comment: おっしゃる通りの方法を試した結果、エラーが消えました！
本当にありがとうございました。

Comment: @maka 解決した場合は、解決済みにしていただけると、Goodです！